# How to make AlertDialogs appear and dissappear successively?

Tags: android, xamarin.android, android-alertdialog, android-thread

I want AlertDialog with message "1" to appear on screen and after 3 seconds to dissappear then I want another AlertDialog with message "2" to appear on screen and after 3 seconds to dissappear and so on and so forth until 5. I have the following code:

```
[Activity(Label = "TestAlertDialogBuilder", MainLauncher = true)]
public class MainActivity : Activity
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

        for (int i=0; i <=5 ; i++)
        {
            //making the program stop so I can see the alert showing and dissappearing
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000);
            ShowAlert(i);
        }
    }

    Dialog dialog;
    public void ShowAlert(int i)
    {
        if (dialog != null)
        {
            dialog.Cancel();
        }
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        alertDialog.SetMessage(i.ToString());
        dialog = alertDialog.Create();
        dialog.Show();
    }
}
```

But after the program's execution after some waiting I only get an AlertDialog with message "5" in it and that is. If someone think another title for my question is more appropriate he can change it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just convert Mohamed Mohaideen AH's answer to C# language.

```
public class MyRunnable : Java.Lang.Object, Java.Lang.IRunnable
{
    private MainActivity mainActivity;

    public MyRunnable(MainActivity mainActivity)
    {
        this.mainActivity = mainActivity;
    }

    public void Run()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i <= 5; i++)
        {
            try
            {
                Java.Lang.Thread.Sleep(3000);
            }
            catch (Java.Lang.Exception e)
            {
                e.PrintStackTrace();
            }
            mainActivity.RunOnUiThread(() =>
            {
                mainActivity.ShowAlert(i);
            });
        }
    }
}


[Activity(Label = "App5", MainLauncher = true)]
public class MainActivity : Activity
{

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);


        MyRunnable myRunnable = new MyRunnable(this);
        Java.Lang.Thread thread = new Java.Lang.Thread(myRunnable);
        thread.Start();

    }
    Dialog dialog;
    public void ShowAlert(int i)
    {
        if (dialog != null)
        {
            dialog.Cancel();
        }
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

        alertDialog.SetMessage("AlertDialog: " + i);
        dialog = alertDialog.Create();
        dialog.Show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Where do I put this code inside or outside the activity I want to use it in?

Comment: It works. The only thing is that it skips `AlertDialog:1` and it goes till `AlertDialog:6`

Answer (score 0):

Issue happened due to blocking UI Main thread until for loop executed. So create seperate thread for dialog & show it in UI.

Try this

```
Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {

        int i = 0;
        @Override
        public void run() {
            for (i=0; i <=5 ; i++)
            {
                //making the program stop so I can see the alert showing and dissappearing
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(3000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        ShowAlert(i);
                    }
                });

            }

        }
    });
   thread.start();

 public void ShowAlert(int i)
{
    if (dialog != null)
    {
        dialog.cancel();
    }
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

    alertDialog.setMessage("" + i);
    dialog = alertDialog.create();
    dialog.show();
}
```

Comment: Why you need in C# are you tried in hybrid development.

Comment: Because I'm programming in Xamarin.Android

Comment: I know Xamarin.Android but i dont have playground to check now so tag xamarin android to attention on xamarin users.